# How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, linux, tlmgr

Debian and Ubuntu have very good texlive packaging. But I'd like to use `tlmgr` to have a more fine-grained control about upgrades and which packages I want to be installed.

So how do I install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian/Ubuntu?

Also how do I make `dpkg` aware that I have TeXLive installed?

Comment: This might be a better fit for Super User or the Ubuntu SE site, since it's really about the Debian/Ubuntu packaging system, not anything specific to LaTeX.

Comment: There's a bug for that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521 . Looks like it might be time to start thinking about an upgrade to a 12.10 pre-release :)

Comment: Ah, there's a PPA for 12.04 too: https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Could you please announce what vanilla is good for? Just because many people like me are using other distributions. I would like to look for a similar package.

Comment: The repos can be tweaked, as detailed here: [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163682)

Comment: I successfully installed TeXLive 2013 on Ubuntu 12.04 following [silex's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/34273) (thanks for that!). Only problem I encountered was a bunch of not really working CTAN mirrors. You may need to change your default mirror by sudo perl install-tl -repository ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN for example.

Comment: Have you seen the difference in your calling and silex's?  Silex's has: `sudo apt-get install perl-tk --no-install-recommends` which I just checked and it works whereas you have for gone the `apt-get` and `perl-tk`.  So I think the source of your problem was not using the exact line.  Here is the output: `dustin@dustin:~$ sudo apt-get install perl-tk --no-install-recommends
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
perl-tk is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the net installer script from [this page on the official tug.org website](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) to install “vanilla” TeXlive.

Tricking Ubuntu into satisfying the package dependencies is more involved and requires using the equivs package. There are basic guidelines for doing so [in this post on TeXblog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/linux/kile-texlive-2008-equivs/) (an unofficial blog). (This page is a bit old and was aimed at older versions of Ubuntu.) The package list there is a bit old, but the same overall procedure should still work. I’m afraid I don’t have a list offhand of what the dummy package should contain; maybe someone else will. (You can always just create new dummy packages as need be if you try to install something it tells you you have unsatisfied texlive dependencies.)

Comment: See also: http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html , section "Vanilla TeX Live on Debian" which is also valid for Ubuntu (since Ubuntu is a Debian based distribution)

Comment: I asked a related question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52388/installing-texlive-on-debian-x86-64-platform. If anyone is having trouble installing vanilla texlive, perhaps some information in that post will help.

Answer (score 432):

These instructions have been updated for Ubuntu 16.04 and TeX Live 2021, they will probably work on most Ubuntu/Debian distributions.

## Installation

Installing "vanilla" TeX Live is not as hard as you think. Things you will need:

- An internet connection.
- About 4 GiB of free space (2 GiB if not installing documentation).
- Root (`sudo`) powers.

**Note**: the instructions are meant for the terminal and for installing the "original" most up-to-date version of `texlive`. If you're uncomfortable with the command line and plenty of `sudo` instructions, you can probably still install the `texlive-full` package from the Software center; you will end up with the "stock" version of `texlive`, which usually lags a bit behind the latest distribution of `texlive`.

### Installation of dependencies

The following packages are required for this guide: `wget`, `perl-tk`. Install them with:

```
sudo apt install wget perl-tk
```

### TeX Live Installer

First the official installer needs to be downloaded with the following commands:

```
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl-20220211
```

The `install-tl-20220211` folder is likely to be named differently. You can probably type `install-tl` and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete the folder name.

Now the installation can begin, run:

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

This starts the installation process. You can change all kind of options here, most of the the default options are correct.
In order to have working executables and man/info -pages after installation where (1) is recommended option in Unix/Linux, while (2) in Windows:

1. Create the following environment variables for finding your new installation in TeXLive 2021:

   ```sh
   export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH    
   export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info
   export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man
   ```

This can be added to `~/.profile` to automatically apply when opening a terminal.

2. You can have the installer create symbolic links for you by changing the options:
   Use <kbd>o</kbd> to change the options and <kbd>l</kbd> to create symbolic links.
   The default locations are correct, so just press <kbd>enter</kbd> to use them.
   Use <kbd>r</kbd> to return to the installation menu.
   If for some reason you overlooked this and ran the installer, it is possible to create the symlinks retrospectively using the command: `tlmgr path add`. See [the relevant documentation](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#path---w32mode-user-admin-add-remove) for more details.

In some cases changing the other options can, of course, be helpful. Not installing the *doc* and *source* trees will save you a lot (1.8 GiB, 50%) of disk space. This comes with the downside of having to look up documentation online, instead of locally.

If you want to reduce disk space further you can also change the installation *scheme* or *collections*, but this will result in not having certain packages installed by default. You can, however, install them later through the TeX live manager.

Press <kbd>i</kbd> to start installation. The full installation is likely to take a long time, say between one and three hours (even on relatively fast connections). As usual, your mileage may vary, but if fewer components are selected in your settings, the process is hastened, and the missing components can be easily installed later.

**Interruptions**:
If, for some reason, the installation is interrupted it can probably be resumed by running the installer again. This will prompt you to continue the installation. If you want to start the installation from the beginning it's probably wise to remove the following installed elements +/- possible elements mentioned in the thread answer [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu/95502#95502)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2021
```

**Failures**:
Such a long installation process may fail due to interruptions in communications or other reasons. In such a case,  you may want to
to restart the installation, but this time choose the smallest configuration that would get it going. Then, you can install all missing components with `sudo tlmgr --gui`.

### Finalising the installation

If everything went well all TeX-related commands should work.
Verify this by checking the output of `which tex`, which should be `/usr/local/bin/tex`.

### Fake packages

Now TeX Live works, but it's also necessary to make Ubuntu think you've installed TeX Live. This can be done with the `equivs` package:

```
sudo apt install equivs --no-install-recommends freeglut3
mkdir -p /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs
equivs-control texlive-local
```

Note: If your `/tmp` is mounted wit `noexec` flag, the build will fail as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/480382/5289). You may just use another directory instead of `/tmp` in this case.

Then, you'll have to edit `texlive-local`. For this use the file provided [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla) corresponding to the version you are installing. For instance, for 2020 use:

```
wget -O texlive-local https://tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2021-ex.txt
```

More information about required edits can be found in [the TeX Live Debian guide](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla).

Now you can build the package and install it (exact name of `.deb` is created in first command below; you can also use tab autocompletion):

```
equivs-build texlive-local
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2021-1_all.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

After this installing `texworks` through the package maintainer won't install TeX Live again.
You can check if this is indeed the case by installing TeX-related packages like `texworks`, `texstudio`, `qtikz` or `kile`.

### Fonts

If you want to install all OpenType and TrueType fonts so you can use them in other programs as well, you'll have to add the TeX Live fonts to the system configuration:

```
sudo cp $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
gedit admin:///etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
```

Remove the line containing `type1` and save. Now run:

```
sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

## Updating

If you have installed from a CD, DVD, or an ISO image, you should update your installation to the most recent version of all packages. To do so, run the following two commands:

```
sudo tlmgr update --self
sudo tlmgr update --all
```

From now on, you can update TeX Live through the TeX Live Manager with the GUI interface:

```
sudo tlmgr --gui
```

It might complain about missing 'Tk', this can be solved by installing `perl-tk`:

```
sudo apt install perl-tk --no-install-recommends
```

### Launcher

You can also create a launcher for your desktop environment:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/tlmgr.desktop << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=TeX Live Manager
Comment=Manage TeX Live packages
GenericName=Package Manager
Exec=pkexec /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr --gui
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-software-update
EOF
```

You may need to logout and login again for the changes to take effect.

**Note**:
If the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` variable is set, use the value of that instead of `~/.local/share/applications`.
It is also possible to use `/usr/share/applications` for a system-wide launcher.

## Upgrading to the next TeX Live

To upgrade you need to download and run the installer again.
Do not forget to have the installer create symbolic links.

It might also be a good idea to run the font section again. You can remove the old distribution(s) by running (for example):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2019
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2020
```

## Uninstalling TeX Live

To remove TeX Live completely you need to undo everything you've done:

- Remove `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and update font cache.
- Remove `/usr/local/texlive`.
- Remove the package created with `equivs` (`sudo apt purge texlive-local`).
- Please, see the thread answer [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95502/13173) for Linux.

## References and sources

- [TeX Live Debian guide](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla)
- [TeX Live Quick install](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)
- [Enrico Gregorio's article for TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf)

Comment: I've installed this succesfully, but I can't for the life of me figure out where the editor texworks is? Its not showing up in my Applications menu

Comment: @masfenix: TeXworks is not installed by TeX Live, you need to install it through the software center.

Comment: @Silex Thanks for the nice howto. Works perfect...

Comment: Thank you for these instructions. They were a life-saver. I wouldn't regard the installation as hard but wouldn't regard it as easy, either...

Comment: How can I install extra packages such as `texlive-publishers`, on `/usr/local/texlive/2013/`?

Comment: @Rasoul: most CTAN packages included in `texlive-publishers` ([list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/lucid/texlive-publishers)) are installed with texlive. Missing CTAN packages can be installed trough the TeX Live Manager.

Comment: @Silex: When I try to install `texlive-publishers` with the command `tlmgr install texlive-publishers` I receive the error `You don't have permission to change the installation in any way`, and if I do `sudo tlmgr install texlive-publishers` I receive the error `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`. I use Ubuntu 12.04 if it does matter.

Comment: @Rasoul: there is a difference between Ubuntu packages (from the Ubuntu repository) and CTAN packages (from CTAN). The latter is what you want. The Ubuntu `texlive-publishers` package can't be installed because you are running vanilla TeX Live. But as `texlive-publishers` is actually a collection of CTAN packages you can install those (if they haven't been installed already). If you have issues, please ask me in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) to avoid extended discussion in the comments.

Comment: The example-link for building the package `texlive-local` ist outdated: http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2013-ex.txt should work instead.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to select (in the installer) `options->create symlinks in standard directories` to create symlinks to the default directories `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/man`, `/usr/local/info`? That way you won't have to do any manual linking.

Comment: @Silex: I have faked the tex installation for Ubuntu as described in your answer. But when I tried to install a dviware package like "catdvi", still the synaptic-package-manager tries to download and install tex-common, texlive-binaries and texlive-common. Although these packages are included in the "Provides:" entry of the equivs script (texlive-local). Any idea?

Comment: Hi, just a small thing to point, in the texlive-local file, we need to explicitly set Package: texlive-local, otherwise I get error in the next step.

Comment: I realise this is how most people proceed but upstream are quite explicit in recommending that TeX Live not be installed with root privileges. (And it works beautifully if you follow their advice and do not do so!)

Comment: For those wondering, `/etc/environment` should be replaced by `/etc/login.defs` when dealing with Debian, according to [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html). In this file you can edit your path.

Comment: For the record, this is one of the best answers on the entire SE network.

Comment: I can't create the `/opt/texbin` symbolic link.  It says there is no such file or directory.  I have checked and I indeed have the `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin` directory, but I don't even have a `/opt` folder

Comment: @MarioS.E.: In that case you can create it: `sudo mkdir /opt`.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, except the step when I am supposed to change `/etc/environment`. Editing the `/etc/environment` file doesn't work. But editing the `~/.bashrc` file works.

Comment: I added more detailed instructions on how to manage /etc/environment.

Comment: I would like to change the icon of tl-manager. I went to `gksudo nautilus` and then at `/usr/share/applications` and i changed the icon and i logged out However, it didn't has an effect

Comment: I can't make `texlua install-getnonfreefonts` work. When I installed TeX Live 2015 following the instructions on tug.org it worked (no \opt stuff, PATHs written in .bashrc), but I didn't know how to install TeXworks correctly. Now when I run `texlua install-getnonfreefonts` as root (after `sudo -s`) i get: `The program 'texlua' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install luatex`. Should I do it or would it be duplicated?  
Note: Running `sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts` results in `sudo: texlua: command not found`.  
`texlua -v` shows the credits.

Comment: Solved. Use `sudo su` instead of `sudo -s` to become root before running `texlua install-getnonfreefonts`.

Comment: On fedora, there is no equivs. I am not sure what is the equivalent of equivs. If the gui complains then one needs to install perl/Tk. What is with different names for same package across distributions?

Comment: @Silke It's time to update this for Ubuntu 16.04!

Comment: Binaries installed in `/usr/local/texlive/...` should be sym linked from `/usr/local/bin`, if anywhere, and not from `/opt`. Different distros use `/opt` in different ways, but I don't know any which would recommend this. (Unless Ubuntu does something really bonkers. Maybe it does.)

Comment: I got the error ` texlive-local depends on freeglut3; however: Package freeglut3 is not installed.` when I was trying to run the command ` equivs-build texlive-local`. Maybe you should add freeglut3 to the list of packages required?

Comment: @ILiketoCode: maybe, but theses dependencies might change. I recommend doing an `apt install -f` after installation of the faked package.

Comment: `which tex` in my machine answers `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tex`. Did I have to set a path for symlinks in the installation options?

Comment: @Silke I have installed texlive-2016 long days ago. A few days ago when I installed updates in my Ubuntu 14.04 texlive-base was also installed. How can I remove texlive-base ubuntu repo packages? my question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389832/texdoc-package-name-results-no-documentation-found).

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Make sure your paths are correct (under TeX Live Installer) and follow the instructions from 'Fake Packages'. Uninstall all packages provided by the `equivs` file.

Comment: @Silke it might be helpful if you would edit your answer so that who has installed the texlive and now want to tell to dpkg that he install texlive like me can use your answer.

Comment: @Silke I follow the instructions from "Fake Packages". but error occurred.https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25533616/

Comment: @Silke `dpkg` error is solved. now see [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25533930/)

Comment: Using `sudo` will be unnecessary, and therefore discouraged, for the vast majority of users, who can just install into their home directory. Installing into `/usr/local` *may* make sense if several users on the system want to use it (and even then, I wouldn't do it).

Comment: Had a problem with PATH. `export` commands didn't work. [This post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/building-r-packages-missing-path-to-pdflatex/) involving RStudio solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Silke `gksu` has been dropped from Debian, Ubuntu 18.04 and Mint 19 (e.g. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=268140). So, probably, some update for the launcher is required.

Comment: `pkexec env PATH=$PATH DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY tlmgr gui` this can be one of replacements to `gksu` containing line I think (more ideas at discussion https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/#comments/292236)

Comment: Is it bad to *not* remove the texlive from apt before doing this?

Comment: I did something similar to this, but installed as a different user, instead of `root`.  If you use `tex`, for example, you would `chown tex:tex /usr/local/texlive/`, then  use `sudo -u tex -g tex` instead of `sudo` on all commands, including the installers. So, you might want to alias `sudo -u tex -g tex ${which tlmgr} update --self --all`. This is useful because exploits in installers don’t have `root` and can only mess with your TeX installation.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Theoretically, it’s fine, so long as your paths are set up correctly so that all users are running the correct binaries.

Comment: Can't make the desktop launcher to work. gedit does not seem to support options d, s and D.

Comment: I followed it for installing Texlive 2021 in ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But `sudo tlmgr update --self` is not working. While giving the full path, like:
`sudo /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self`, then it's working.

Comment: Great guide, but unfortunately, it does not seem to work on WSL. `equivs-build` says: *"fakeroot, while creating message channels: Function not implemented"* Seems as if I need to stay at my old version from 2017 ...

Comment: @raf : use `sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --gui` then in Actions, you can update the symbolic links. Solution found in this message : https://askubuntu.com/a/137836/376526

Comment: When attempting to do a shared global install, ensure that the `umask` is set to `0022` such that the resulting stuff is readable / executable by others.

Comment: @Tobard I am able to run e.g., `sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --version` but tlmgr --gui gives me a segmentation fault error. I thought it was permissions-related, so I ended up just adding `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux` to `secure_path`, but that didn't help. Do you have any idea what could be causing the segmentation fault issue?

Comment: I installed texlive this way and everything worked, but I can't run `tlmgr gui`. Running `sudo tlmgr --gui` results in `[1]    687053 segmentation fault  sudo tlmgr --gui`. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 38):

I wrote a script that automates Silex's answer and does (optionally) a lot more. It supports Ubuntu versions 12.04 up to the current version.

Download [`install-tl-ubuntu`](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) and run it as

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

To download that script, run

```
wget https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/raw/master/install-tl-ubuntu && chmod +x ./install-tl-ubuntu
```

Below I give the list of features from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu)

- installs TeX Live 2013

  - automatically finds the fastest repository
  - gives updated progress of the install
  - restarts automatically if install fails
- `tlmgr` can then be used to keep your install up-to-date
- notifies `apt` so that apt does not try to install the Ubuntu `texlive-*`
  packages as dependencies (e.g. if you do `sudo apt-get install lyx`)
- links to the folder where Ubuntu installs TeX files so that when you
  install Ubuntu packages (e.g. FoilTeX and noweb) with LaTeX files,
  they will be available
- adds TeX Live fonts to be used system-wide
- other font-related conveniences

  - tells AppArmor to allow Evince to access the TeX Live fonts
  - can install TrueType fonts that user provides (`--truetype-dir`)
  - can install IvriTeX Hebrew fonts (`--hebrew`)
- optionally installs additional LaTeX files for common journals that are not included in TeX Live 2013 (`--more-tex`)
- works non-interactively and thus can be added to a batch install script
- `tlmgr` can be run from the desktop menu (if 'gksu' package is
  installed)
- install can be done from an ISO file (-`-iso`)

For more details, see

```
./install-tl-ubuntu --help
```

Comment: Many many thanks for that. I updated Ubuntu to 14.04 and that broke the LaTeX completely on my machine. 'Usual' instillation didn't work but your script worked like a charm. One question though. I downloaded `install-tl-ubuntu` to my home directory. After installation was complete it left behind some folders: `install-tl-20140417`, `debian-control-texlive-in.txt`, `install-tl-1.log`, `install-tl-ubuntu_EXTRAS.log`, `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, `mirrorCandidates.log`and `mirrorWgets.log`. Can they all/some be deleted?

Comment: @radek Glad it was useful. You do not need those files anymore.

Comment: @scottkosty Looks very nice! (I don't use Ubuntu/Debian, though.) Can you run it as a non-root user, as upstream recommends? Even better, could you have it create a non-root user to manage the installation and then proceed as that user? (So the user would also then be used for subsequent updates etc.)

Comment: @cfr (I'm sincerely sorry for the very late reply, not sure how I missed this). No, unfortunately it cannot be run as non-root. I think this would be nice (and even recommended, as you say). Patches are welcome :)

Comment: @scottkosty Not exactly a patch, but I have written [instructions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/) in supplemental answer here. This includes coverage for Debian/Ubuntu, although I can't test that myself. (But somebody else helped with this bit, as you'll see from the comments.)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you've done, but that is probably not the best way to allow Ubuntu-installed TeX stuff to be used. The best is to add it as an additional tree. (I asked a question about how this should best be handled a while back, and this was the answer I got from, I think, Norbert, if I remember correctly. I regard that as definitive for TeX Live in the absence of protestations to the contrary from one of the other developers.)

Comment: Also, if you do not test to ensure that you are on a system you wrote the script for, I think you should. Yes, people should read what it says on the tin. But, no, people won't necessarily even realise it is a tin. ;)

Comment: The readme in github says that the current version "TeX Live 2016".   Is there also support for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I have heard from many Ubuntu 16.04 users that install-tl-ubuntu works well. I have also used it on a few Ubuntu 16.04 installations and it works smoothly for me. There might be a warning that 16.04 isn't yet "officially" supported but that's just because I haven't gotten around to confirming and tweaking the TeX Live -> Ubuntu package mappings for 16.04. But again, I have not heard about a single problem specific to Ubuntu 16.04. If you happen to use the `--hebrew` option of install-tl-ubuntu, I'd be interested in hearing from you regarding whether it works well.

Comment: I did install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew --more-tex on Ubuntu 16.04. So far it works well. I managed to compile this Hebrew document: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~yoavg/tech-notes/heblatex/hebexample.tex well. Thank you very much for this useful script!

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi great! Thanks for confirming. Note (just in case you are curious) that we also have a couple of LyX Hebrew manuals. See /usr/share/lyx/doc/he/Intro.lyx and /usr/share/lyx/doc/he/Tutorial.lyx

Comment: @scottkosty I am also now trying your script for use in Hebrew on 16.04 (I only added the --hebrew option). Basically the Hebrew works, but your script does not install the culmus-latex package (https://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/) which, as far as I understand it, is needed in order to use the entire variety of the culmus fonts, as well as the Nikud. This is, of course, unless you use XeTeX. I also did not manage to install it using `tlmgr` as it is not in the repository, nor by the instructions provided by the package. Anyway, thanks for the script!

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler thanks for this feedback. It is good to know that the Hebrew works (in fact, I just tested with a 40 page non-trivial Hebrew document and pdfTeX compiles it well). I know nothing of Hebrew or fonts, but if you are interested in helping me incorporate a wider variety of Hebrew fonts, please open an issue on the install-tl-ubuntu github page and we can work together to improve things. I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @scottkosty I opened an issue. But I'm not a programmer, and rather new to Linux, so I don't think I can help with the technical side of things...

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler well together we make one Hebrew-speaking programmer so we will figure it out :). I promise I will take a look at the Github issue but not sure exactly when that will happen. For archival purposes (e.g. in case other Hebrew users happen along these comments and want to follow the progress or give input), the github issue is here: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/issues/27

Comment: I tried running the script, but it would restart repeatedly (11 times) and then abort.  When I checked the log file, I'm getting a 404 not found on "http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan//install-tl-unx.tar.gz".  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: @Zach can you open an issue on the github repo? One solution might be for you to manually select a repository using the `--repository` option. See the output of `install-tl-ubuntu --help`.

Answer (score 18):

Some comments:

1. According to the Ubuntu package listing, the [texlive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/texlive) package is a dummy package whose only purpose is to install a decent selection of dependencies.  So it is possible to install this texlive package *without* installing any of its dependencies.  This requires using `dpkg` instead of `aptitude` (as far as I can see, and I don't know if it's possible through the synaptic package manager): passing the `--ignore-depends=texlive` option to `dpkg` will cause it to forego the dependency check.  Then anything that depends on `texlive` will afterwards install fine (I believe), though if something depends on, say, `texlive-bin` then it *will* complain.
2. Whilst checking the options for `aptitude` and `dpkg` for the above, I came across the following snippet from `aptitude`: the command

   ```
   aptitude install texlive&m
   ```

   will mark `texlive` as having been manually installed.  (Note that the `&` will probably need some sort of shell escaping to avoid it being interpreted by the shell.)  I *believe* this basically says to the system "I've installed this myself, so you can stop bothering with it.".
3. Possibly the easiest solution (and the one I use myself) is to simply ignore the system one and install your own version as well.  If you do this right, you get the best of both worlds because one possible problem with *replacing* the system version with your own version is that the upgade may break some dependencies from other packages.  It's less likely with something like TeX, but you can imagine that lots might go wrong if you upgrade one of the core system libraries without upgrading all the programs that use it.  This is what the `/usr/local` directory is for.  Put your installation of TeXLive in `/usr/local/texlive` or somewhere using the standard installation (as mentioned by frabjous, for example).  By ensuring that `/usr/local` appears before `/usr/bin` in your path, and that `$TEXMFCNF` points to the right place, you can effectively ignore the system installation whilst being able to fall back on it if necessary.

Comment: Except that by policy none of the packages depend on the "decent selection packages" e.g. texlive since they are subject to change to something like equivs will be required.

Comment: @Dima: I was afraid of that.  In that case, I'd go for option 3 with option 2 if you really don't want to install the system version.

Comment: Ad 2: packages marked as "manually installed" are still regular packages.  The difference is that if all packages that depend on them are removed the "manually installed" packages will be kept.  In contrast, if all packages that depend on an "automatically installed" package are removed, the package itself will be removed too.  By default, manually installed packages are those that you actually select for installation in aptitude, automatically installed are those pulled in as dependencies. You can override this by marking a package as manually or automatically installed. So 2 would not work.

Comment: @Jan Hlavecek: Thanks for the clarification.  Option 3 seems best, then.

Comment: concerning option 3, you don't need to set `TEXMFCNF` and it is recommended _not_ to set it. Setting the `PATH` is enough.

Comment: In bash, does one need to type `aptitude install texlive&m` or `aptitude install texlive\&m`?

Comment: @Lao: I don't use `bash` so I don't know.  I'm pretty sure that the first won't work, but I don't know about the second.

Comment: (3) spells trouble and confusion, in my opinion. I really wouldn't recommend it. I'm sure you know what you are doing and can avoid the pitfalls, but for mere mortals it is fraught with danger.

Answer (score 18):

> **PLEASE THINK BEFORE EDITING! Please do NOT edit this answer in ways which render it distro-specific.** Although this question specifically addresses Debian/Ubuntu systems, it serves to provide information to users of GNU/Linux more generally. The way things work on *your* system may not be the way they work on *all* GNU/Linux systems - not even all Debian-based systems.

Note that [upstream recommend ***not*** installing as root](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). Installing as root introduces a level of risk and has no benefits whatsoever.

Note that I trust the people who are in charge of TeX Live. However, I have been given reason to believe that they are fallible and fallible beings screw up however competent and however well-intentioned they are. Moreover, servers get hacked, downloads get corrupted or intercepted. Shit, basically, happens.

The crucial point is that ***there is zero benefit to installing with root privileges. All it gets you is an increased security risk.*** While it may be small, I see no reason to take it.

It is possible to install and manage the installation as your ordinary user. However, that only protects your system directories. Your home directory - where you probably keep all of your personal files and projects - remains exposed. Fortunately, it is easy to protect `/home` as well.

If you want to follow upstream's advice, then, here is how I do it...

## Set up a dedicated user/group and create a suitable home for it

This is the only part you need root privileges for.

The following are generic instructions which should work for most GNU/Linux distros. If you are using a Debian based system or another distro which features the `adduser` script, see the note below for an easier method. Otherwise, use the `useradd` command as follows.

### *Generic GNU/Linux distro: `useradd`*

```
sudo useradd -d /usr/local/texlive -m -r -U -s /bin/sh texlive
```

This creates a new user, `texlive`, as a member of a new group, `texlive`. It creates a home directory for `texlive` at `/usr/local/texlive`.

If you have previously installed TeX Live from upstream, omit the `-m` flag from the above command. Instead, once you have created the new user, do this:

```
sudo chown -Rh texlive:texlive /usr/local/texlive
```

Be sure to set a password:

```
sudo passwd texlive
```

You will be asked to choose and confirm a password. Note that what you type will not show up on the screen at all. Just type the password and hit enter. Then do the same to confirm.

If you wish, you can choose some other name for the user/group, so long as it is unique on your system. Suppose you want to use `tladmin:tladmin`, then you need

```
sudo useradd -d /usr/local/texlive -m -r -U -s /bin/sh tladmin
sudo passwd tladmin
```

or, if you've previously installed TeX Live as another user, omit the `-m` flag and add

```
sudo chown -Rh tladmin:tladmin /usr/local/texlive
```

In what follows, `<username for texlive>` denotes the user name and `group of texlive>` denotes the group. So, in our examples, both are `texlive` or `tladmin`.

### *Debian-based distro: `adduser`*

If you are using Debian or a Debian derivative then, according to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182180/why-is-the-home-directory-not-created-when-i-create-a-new-user) and given [Andrew Cashner's experience](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/187379?noredirect=1#comment635207_187379), you should probably use `adduser` rather than `useradd`. According to Andrew:

```
sudo adduser texlive
```

or, if you want to use a different user name, such as `tladmin`

```
sudo adduser tladmin
```

is sufficient but notice that this will create an additional directory `/home/texlive` or `/home/tladmin` which the `useradd` method does not. In this case, `<username for texlive>`'s home will be `/home/<username for texlive>` and *not* `/usr/local/texlive`. Moreover, `<username for texlive>`'s primary group will depend on the defaults for your system: you might get `<username for texlive>:<username for texlive>` (e.g. `texlive:texlive` or `tladmin:tladmin`) or you might get `<username for texlive>:staff` (e.g. `texlive:staff` or `tladmin:staff`) or `<username for texlive>:users` (e.g. `texlive:users` or `tladmin:users`). You can use

```
groups <username for texlive>
```

to discover which group `<username for texlive>` is assigned to. For example, use

```
groups texlive
```

if `texlive` is the name of the user you added, or

```
groups tladmin
```

for `tladmin`.

If the result includes `<username for texlive>` (e.g. `texlive` or `tladmin`), use this group in what follows. Otherwise, you probably only get a single group listed e.g. `users` and should use that one. In the following, I'll call this group `<group of texlive>` and denote the user name you're using by `<username for texlive>`. If you have not installed from upstream before:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive
sudo chown -Rh <username for texlive>:<group of texlive> /usr/local/texlive
```

If you have installed from upstream before, then just:

```
sudo chown -Rh <username for texlive>:<group of texlive> /usr/local/texlive
```

## Switch to the new user before installing

Now login as `<username for texlive>`:

```
su -l <username for texlive>
```

Give the password and you will be in `<username for texlive>`'s home directory. That is, you will be in `/usr/local/texlive`. (If you used the Debian method above, `cd /usr/local/texlive` to move from the home directory.)

Now follow Silex's instructions but omit all occurrences of `sudo`. You don't need them.

Note that this method not only protects your system directories, ***it also protects your home***. The `<username for texlive>` user cannot write to your normal home directory. So even if somebody screws up and the installer tries to delete all your documents, it will not be allowed to do so. In fact, if you were to get any permissions errors whatsoever, that would be a red flag. The installer is not supposed to touch anything outside `/usr/local/texlive` at all.

## Aftercare: when to use root

You will need `sudo` to install the fake packages and to integrate TeX Live's fonts into the system configuration. That's because these steps involve system directories. The fake packages get installed for the system and the font configuration involves altering files in `/etc`. That all necessarily requires root privileges.

## Maintenance: updating your installation

When you are ready to update TeX Live, simply login as `<username for texlive>` prior to running the update:

```
su -l <username for texlive>
# give the password
tlmgr update --all
```

Do **not** use `sudo` or switch to root. The whole point is that `tlmgr` runs as an *unprivileged* user and cannot touch your home or system directories.

In general, if you want to change anything under `/usr/local/texlive`, `su <username for texlive>` before you do it. If you want to do something in `/etc` or under `/opt`, you need root privileges (`sudo` or similar).

---

## Loosely related notes

The use of single configuration files in `/etc` seems to be going out of fashion. If you find that `/etc/environment` does not set your `PATH`, it may be somewhere else. For example, on some systems, `PATH` is set in `/etc/profile` and should be extended by adding a file named something like `/etc/profile.d/texmf.sh` for shells such as `sh` or `bash`:

```
# /etc/profile.d/texlive.sh 
if [ $UID != 0 ]
then
        [ -d "<path to binaries>" ] && export PATH="<path to binaries>:${PATH}"
fi
```

This avoids adding TeX Live binaries automatically to root's `PATH`. In order to avoid needing to adapt this file when you install a new edition of TeX Live, you can use a system of symbolic links.

```
cd /usr/local/texlive
ln -s <YYYY>/bin/x86_64-linux bin.<YYYY>
ln -s <YYYY> current.<YYYY>
ln -s bin.<YYYY> bin
ln -s current.<YYYY> current
```

Then`/etc/profile.d/texmf.sh` can contain just

```
# /etc/profile.d/texlive.sh 
if [ $UID != 0 ]
then
        [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/bin" ] && export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/bin:${PATH}"
fi
```

and `PATH` will be set to include the current binaries automatically. When you install a new edition of TeX Live, you just add further links (2 per edition) and adjust the `current` and `bin` link to point to whichever edition you want to be active. This can all be done as `<username for texlive>`, with no need for root privileges. (That is, the `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d` must be created with root privileges, but you need not touch this file when installing or activating a new edition of TeX Live.)

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion.  I’ve often been tempted to install TeX Live as root because some editors (Emacs, for one) open `.sty` files upon compilation errors, and then I’m in danger of modifying the files without noticing what I’m doing (absent-minded).  This approach prevents that as well as protecting `/home`.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks. That's a good point. My editor tends to do that too. I've never installed TL as myself I went from root to a special user. But it is definitely another good reason to keep a separate account. It also means if there's anything of your own you don't want to touch, you can stick it in TEXMFLOCAL which is managed by the dedicated user as well. (At least, using the above instructions it ends up that way.) This method is really, really easy to use. It really is just creating a new user with a special home and setting it up that is a little fiddly. But you only do that once....

Comment: I installed TeXLive per your instructions on Debian, but with `useradd` I ended up with a fairly crippled user account for the `texlive` user. In particular, I was unable to set the path, which meant I couldn't use `tlmgr`. I tried again using the newer utility `adduser` (simply `adduser texlive` with no additional options required) and everything worked better. The only thing I had to do as root was create a `/usr/local/texlive` directory and `chown texlive:texlive /usr/local/texlive` so that the `texlive` user could install there.

Comment: On `adduser` vs. `useradd`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182180/why-is-the-home-directory-not-created-when-i-create-a-new-user

Comment: @AndrewCashner The thing is, `adduser` is distro-specific. Some distros do not provide such a wrapper at all (e.g. mine). I'll see if anything about `useradd` has changed, though. Thanks for the heads up. Strange that `useradd` would be crippled on Debian. As I say, `adduser` is not generally available.

Comment: @AndrewCashner I've updated in light of your comments. Unfortunately, I cannot test this personally as my system does not have the `adduser` wrapper. The answer there which claims `useradd` is 'deprecated` is wrong, at least as a general claim. `adduser` is just a Debian wrapper around `useradd` as far as I know. In any case, `adduser` is not a generic GNU/Linux command and clearly is ***not*** deprecated on other systems. (I realise this question asked about Debian/Ubuntu specifically, but it is the only question on this so it seems reasonable to include information for other distros.)

Comment: @cfr Just to clarify: If you use `adduser` the system will take care of setting up the home folder (which, as you say, is `/home/texlive`) with suitable `.profile` and other defaults. Then you still have to create the texlive folder and give its ownership to `texlive` by doing `sudo mkdir /usr/local/texlive && chown texlive:texlive /usr/local/texlive`. After that you can login as `texlive` and do the installation.

Comment: I would suggest setting null shell for user `texlive` (`/bin/false` or `/bin/nologin`), then using `tlmgr` with `sudo -u texlive tlmgr`. If `$PATH` isn't properly set, `sudo env PATH="$PATH" /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr path add` should sort that out (use `20XX` according to your version).

Comment: @JonathanY. Not all Linux distros have `sudo` by default. And I don't honestly see any reason for adding this complication. Moreover, `sudo` is complicated in various ways and its configuration is highly system and distro dependent, so it is difficult to give instructions. But what is the advantage? I realise it means somebody can't log in as `texlive`, but I don't see any particular benefit in that. Note that part of the point of my post is that you don't need to specify the `20XX` in the path.

Comment: Well the answer calls `sudo` several times as it is; the advantage is what you say, but I disagree on the benefit: setting a separate password adds an attack vector *plus* the potential to lose it / cost to remember it. You could make it random, and use `sudo` to reset it every time you use `tlmgr` (which shouldn't be often), but what's the point? Also, setting `$PATH` a single time is comparable to installing fake packages -- there's no added cost here.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you mean that the work user needn't set their `$PATH` to include the correct directory in `/usr/local/texlive`, then I missed that. How so?

Comment: I use `tlmgr` often. I don't know why you claim I 'shouldn't'. Anyone on a system without `sudo` will translate the above appropriately. (I doubt I used `sudo` where I've given it above, but this is primarily a Debian/Ubuntu question, so I gave the code that way here.) The `texlive` account has fewer privileges than my regular user account. I can easily reset the password if I need to. I don't see any significant increase in risk from managing the installation directly as `texlive`, which greatly simplifies things. Your last comment is correct, though. (But I seem to have presupposed it....)

Comment: @JonathanY. Thanks for pointing out the omission. Please see edit above. Note, too, that even if you rarely use `tlmgr`, you may well need to manage `TEXMFLOCAL`, which is much more conveniently done by a user who can log in than by one who cannot. Of course, you *can* manage without this, but it complicates things significantly. Even if all you want to do is install the non-free fonts, it is easier to do it this way. I also think that there is less danger of accidentally modifying the contents of `/usr/local/texlive` as root this way. You can set up a distinctive prompt for the `texlive`user.

Comment: An unrelated follow-up question on this post: does this setup offer any mitigating factor to the risk (to one's home directory, among other things) presented by running texlive executables (which, presumably, most do with their own user)? Even if we authenticate an image as signed by the tl team, does `tlmgr` use any cryptography to authenticate updates? Can one easily set up a process that compiles Tex sources as the unprivileged user?

Comment: @JonathanY. No. This offers no additional protection when using TeX Live. It only protects you while installing and updating/maintaining it. If you install malicious binaries, then you are in trouble. However, note that this would require something like pdfTeX itself to be altered, because TeX will not usually allow either arbitrary command execution or changes above the working directory. By default. You can change it to be either stricter or less strict.

Comment: @JonathanY. For installation/updates, checksums are checked and the checksum list is verified. However, if verification fails, installation continues by default. This can be disabled or enforced using custom options. See tlmgr's manual page for details.

Comment: @cfr, interesting approach. But, a practical question, do you consider TeXLive (or CTAN for that sake) as being riskier than, e.g., Ubuntu or Debian standard repositories?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes. But that's not really the point. The point is the general principle of not doing things with higher privileges than necessary. There's a reason I don't write my TeX documents as root: it is entirely unnecessary.  Note that when you install programmes from your distro's repositories, installation scripts may well drop privileges for the sake of security. Neither the TeX Live installer nor `tlmgr` drops privileges. If you run them as root, they do everything as root.

Comment: @gusbrs It is left to the user to follow TeX Live's own advice or not, just as it is left to you whether to run other things as advised or not. It isn't a question of the repos being riskier or not. It is a question of it being riskier to ignore upstream's advice. Upstream advise installing without privileges. This is the only sensible advice: privileges are entirely unnecessary, therefore they should not be used. This is a basic strategy: don't do anything with more privileges than necessary. If you must run something as root, drop privileges as soon as possible.

Comment: @gusbrs In one sense, *of course* CTAN and TL are riskier than Debian/Ubuntu standard repositories. CTAN does not scrutinise the packages uploaded. TL does not scrutinise them either. They would not accept anything obviously malicious or obviously inadvertently problematic, but there is no active scrutiny. In another sense, of course the standard repos are riskier because they are the source of software with far more potential for damage. So which kind of risk are you asking about?

Comment: @gusbrs You can actually convert your installation to a ownership by a non-privileged user. If you do that, you can run `tlmgr` without privileges. Basically, create the new user and then run, say `chown -Rh texlive:texlive /usr/local/texlive` as root or with `sudo`. Then manage the installation as `texlive`.

Comment: @cfr, actually I hadn't taken the thought that deep. I was just thinking of the installation of a regular program trough the repos, let's say `texlive` itself. But you are correct in pointing the two kinds of risk.

Comment: @cfr, I've been trying this out, and have a small suggestion. In the update section (at least in my settings) if I use `su texlive` the path is not set appropriately. For that, I have to use `su -l texlive`, with which I get the environment variables also set. (I did not set TeXLive paths globally, but trough `/etc/profile.d`).

Comment: @gusbrs What do you mean by not setting them globally? If you set them in `/etc/profile.d`, they should be set for all users.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for the suggestion about `su -l`. I've added that even though I'm not sure why it is needed on some systems, because I don't think it will hurt anything even where it is not needed.

Comment: @cfr, I mean I haven't set the path in `/etc/environment`, but I guess my terms were not adequate, given that `/etc/profile.d` indeed sets it for all users.

Comment: @cfr, I'm working within a somewhat common environment: Linux Mint 18.2, which is akin to Ubuntu 16.04. What happened is that, setting the path with `/etc/profile.d` and changing users with `su texlive` the path did not come along. I really cannot tell you why. If I logged out and then logged in as texlive, it did work fine. Resorting to `su -l` sorted out the issue for me.

Comment: I set it in `/etc/profile.d`, too. But I'm on a different system and different systems will configure things differently. (Actually, 2 systems, but they are both different.)

Comment: A minor suggestion / request: to help differentiate between the actual `TeXLive` and the "artificial / workaround" user *texlive*, could you perhaps rename the user in your guidelines above to, for instance *tex**a**live* ?

Comment: Or, will it not work if the username is anything but *texlive* ?

Comment: Here's what I did in the end: username *tex**a**live* but in the `mkdir` and `chown` lines kept `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: Help needed: `which tex` returned `/usr/local/texlive/.......` alright while "logged in" to the *texalive* user in terminal, then typed `exit` and hit enter and `which tex` no longer returned anything, also not upon logging back in to *texalive*. What am I missing?!

Comment: PS: am testing this on a virtual machine first and I took a snapshot right after the installation completed and I updated the PATH's, so I can always return to the machine state where `which tex` still worked.

Comment: Thanks for that! -- Any idea why the successful installation (as evidenced by `which tex`) could have gone missing (?) - no response to `which tex` - upon executing an `exit` command (which here roughly triggers a change of user from `tladmin` back to the original user), for example, in the very same shell/command line instance in my more recent comment/question?

Comment: `which tex` also returns nothing if (from the virtual machine state freshly after the successful install) I switch with `su main-user` to the main-user (and also does not return when I switch back again with `su tladmin` to the "texlive" user).

Comment: Ok, I thought I managed to solve it (or at least find a viable workaround), but apparently not quite yet: if I execute the three `export` commands again (e.g. *not* as `tladmin` but as the main/normal user), `which tex`, `man tex`, etc work. However, if I close that terminal and start a new one, things are reset and I need to `export` again. What am I doing wrong(ly)?

Comment: SOLVED, I think. Added the three lines to `$HOME/.profile` of the main/normal user (cf., for instance, http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-310003.4.1). Saved. Logged-out-and-back-in. `which tex` works.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You should be able to set those system-wide, as I did, in `/etc`. However, exactly what you need to change in `/etc` is system-dependent. For me, it means adding a new file in `/etc/profile.d` but, for you, it might require something different. It depends how your Linux distro configures `PATH`. You should not set `MANPATH` etc. on any recent distro of which I'm aware - only `PATH`. However, changes in `/etc` won't take effect until your next login. (I don't know what that means on a virtual machine.)

Comment: The check for 'normal' users in the profile script `if [ \`whoami\` != "root" ]; then ... fi` should rather be checking which user id is used, i.e. `if (( $EUID == 0 )); then ... fi` (requires bash). This is more portable and more secure as the su is not always called root, but it has always 0 as id.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン What's the difference between `EUID` and `UID`? Is `EUID` available everywhere `UID` is?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I guess `$UID` would be better since `EUID` is newer and I'm not clear whether it is supported everywhere. (E.g. long-term support editions of RHEL etc., BSD etc.) So maybe `if [ $UID != 0 ]; then ... fi` ...

Comment: @cfr I am not 100% sure right now, my Linux knowledge is very dependable on my notes. I remember looking it up and that it is now the recommended practice. It should be available in the new kernels, and since we're talking about installing the latest texlive version, we can assume that the user had an reasonably updated system. It certainly works on Centos, Ubuntu, and I think I tried it on Suse. Whoami is not a good idea, because that's a script calling the `$USER` variable and not a shell native. That basically defeats the purpose of portability you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I agree about `whoami`. I've edited above to use `UID` instead. `UID` is available on BSD-like systems and will be in RHEL, whereas I'm not certain about `EUID`, which only seems to have been introduced to POSIX circa 2013. There's no guarantee that a new TL means a new OS. One reason people install vanilla TL is precisely that their distro's packages supply only a very outdated version. So, if anything, this is more likely relevant to people on older systems.

Comment: And one more things I noticed. You don't necessarily have to install it in `/usr/local/`, it works everywhere. You can keep your installation completely local. I do it that way, because I'm using this approach for many other programs I need to install. As long as every user can read and X it, it's fine. You can go a bit further and simply add the users who should be allowed to use it to a group. Then you can get rid of the world permissions currently necessary.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes, you can. But it makes things much easier not to do that. People who understand their systems well enough to cope with the additional complications do not need my step-by-step instructions. There isn't actually any security reason not to have world permissions, really. At least, no reason that doesn't apply to every other programme. And there is no security advantage to avoiding `/usr/local`.

Comment: Sorry for the inappropriate edit. I thought you could review it before it was acceppted.

Comment: @ArchStanton I didn't even know you'd edited this answer.

Comment: @ArchStanton I'm not sure if I saw it or not, actually, but don't worry about it. I just put a banner up to (try to) stop people keep editing it in ways that make it much more distro- or distro-version specific. If people leave me a comment, I can figure out whether I need a 'if you have X, do Y, but if you have A, do B' or whatever. This is how the adding-new-user stuff turned out to go, whereas if it had just been 'updated', it wouldn't have worked on other systems (including mine!). Different distros and different installations of the same distro can be very, very different.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use of the comment in `/etc/profile.d/texmf.sh`?

Comment: @ArchStanton I just put it here when writing the answer so that the name of the file is tied as closely as possible to the content. I don't have it in `/etc/profile.d/cfr_texlive.sh` on my system, which is the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because I saw other files in `/etc/profile.d/` with their full name in the first line as a comment. I thought it was to distinguish them if they are concatenated.

Comment: @ArchStanton Well, that too. Lots of files have this just for tracking, I think. If a file ends up in the wrong place it can tell you where home is. A bit like teaching small children their addresses.

Comment: I have just installed TL2019 on a Fedora 30 box. I had to run `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/texlive/` in order to have `[ -d /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux ]` return true (`which tex` was failing because the test in `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh` returned false). `/usr/local/texlive/` only had `rwx------` permissions, while every other directory in `/usr/local/` had `drwxr-xr-x` permissions (`755` in octal).

Answer (score 14):

A paper about installing TeX Live 2011 on Ubuntu and other GNU/Linux distributions can be found on

[ArsTeXnica, vol. 10 (in Italian)](http://www.guit.sssup.it/arstexnica/)
[TUGboat, vol. 32-1 (issue 100) (in English)](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents32-1.html)
[Die TeXnische Komödie, issue 3/2011 (in German)](http://www.dante.de/DTK.html)

Thanks to Karl Berry and Barbara Beeton for the revision of the TUGboat version, and to Heiko Oberdiek and Herbert Voß for the German translation.

The papers are, up to now, available only to members of GuIT, TUG, and Dante, respectively, but will be public in due time.

Note: the Italian and English versions are about TeX Live 2010, but it's sufficient to change 2010 into 2011 in all the steps.

Comment: it seems that access to the English version is restricted to tug members

Comment: Yes, as are also the other versions. TUG discloses articles to everybody after one year, IIRC.

Comment: @egreg I have a question about `perl-tk`. In your [guide](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/texlive-ubuntu.pdf) you state to install it using Synaptic. Silke, in his answer above, says to write `sudo apt-get install perl-tk --no-install-recommends`. I wanted to know if it is the same thing.

Comment: @Marco Yes, that should be the same, as Synaptic is an interface to `apt`.

Answer (score 9):

I have successfully installed TeXLive on Ubuntu 11.10 on a 64bit machine.

I have condensed the steps linked to in [frabjou's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1094/1783), which, while the instructions are clear, may leave many *buntu users wondering "how do I change the PATH variable?"

```
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xvf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl*
sudo ./install-tl
```

- at prompt, enter "i" to install
- change PATH, I did so by editing ~/.bashrc:

  - 64 bit

    ```
    # PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
    cat "export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
    ```
  - 32 bit:

    ```
    cat "export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
    ```

*caveat* see the [tug instructions](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) for more details; e.g. if TeXLive 2011 has been previously installed, it needs to be removed

Answer (score 4):

### Fake packages

Following up Silex's excellent write-up: I have put a fake package `texlive-dummy` created by the equivs-build process into [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~krlmlr/+archive/ppa). ([Package source](https://github.com/krlmlr/texlive-dummy-ubuntu).) If you are on Ubuntu 13.04, the following will provide the necessary dependencies without having to generate a package:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:krlmlr/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install texlive-dummy
```

<strike>I intend to update this package to more recent versions of Ubuntu.</strike>

See [Scott's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171564/8057) for a much better solution.

Answer (score 3):

[It should be noted that there is now a much easier way to install up to date versions of TeXLive. There are now official backports of newer versions of TeXLive, as detailed here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012)

This gets you to at least 2012, and it looks like newer versions of Ubuntu have 2013, so you can probably pull this package out of their repertories without damaging anything, though I wouldn't swear by that and you should consult an Ubuntu expert first.

Comment: `texdoc`,`tlmgr` which get's automatic updates for all new packages will be missing with 2012 `backports` and even distro specific latex packages are very old and cannot updated with `tlmgr`. Hence vanilla [texlive installation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) is the way to do for taking advantage of full power of texlive distro and being latest.

Comment: @texenthusiast Ah, I didn't know that. Looking at the changelog once you get the newest version of ubuntu they are keeping the package up to date at least. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: actually [backports](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/150473?noredirect=1#comment121111_1092) was mentioned by `naught101` user in comments. So I think `backports` is not too much advisable compared to the `vanilla install` if possible sorry to say delete the answer. But some people prefer to be with ubuntu's ppa also instead of being _over_ latest. finally take your decision.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing a guide for someone else that expands on the excellent answers here, so I will post it here as well.  The first section is roughly equivalent to cfr’s answer.

#### Installing TeX Live on Debian/Ubuntu

You do not need to install TeX Live as root, although that will work.  The reason you might not want to is security: if you install as root, every package install script runs `sudo root`.

If you already have a copy of TeX Live installed, you should remove it with `apt`.  You might also want to `sudo rm -r /usr/local/texlive` if it exists and start fresh.

You can create a new user and group that owns only the TeX installation with

```
sudo adduser --system --group --home-dir /usr/local/texlive tex
```

This will create a new user and group account that cannot log in and owns only the local TeX Live directory.  You can, however, run commands as `sudo -u tex`.  The sole purpose of this account is to run TeX installers and updates.  That way, they only have permission to read and modify your TeX distribution.

Having done this, you want to make sure that only TeX can add and remove files in the TeX directory, but everyone else can use `cd` and `ls` on it.

```
sudo chown tex:tex /usr/local/texlive
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/texlive
```

You can now install TeX Live, as tex, to this new directory that TeX owns.  From the directory where you unpacked the TeX Live installer:

```
chmod 755 install-tl
sudo -u tex -E ./install-tl
```

The option `-u tex` means run as the user tex, and `-E` means preserve the environment variables, for example `LANG` to determine the language.  By default, the installer should put the files in the new directory you just created, `/usr/local/texlive/`.  Since tex owns this directory, it can.

You don’t need to use `sudo` to run commands like `lualatex` or `pdflatex`.  You’d run those from your regular account.  The only time you need to run as `tex` is when you’re updating the TeX installation, which `tex` owns.

#### Updating Your Configuration

First, you need to add your TeX Live directories to your `PATH`, `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH` environment variables, ahead of the system directories.  Reposting from above: you can save the following to a file named `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh` and it will load the next time you open a shell.

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export PATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
export INFOPATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export MANPATH
```

Update this if you are running a version other than 2020, of course.

If you `exec bash -login` to reload your environment, `latex --version` should tell you that it was installed from TeX Live, not your distribution.  You should also be able to run `man latex` and `info latex`.

The command to update your tex installation is long and annoying, but you can create an easy-to-remember alias.  The command for this is:

```
alias update-tex='sudo -u tex -E $(which tlmgr) update --self --all'
```

You would need to add it to your profile (either the file in `/etc/profile.d`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile` if it exists) as well as whichever of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.cshrc`, `~/.kshrc`, etc. you use to set it for non-login shells.  You could also set your aliases in a file such as `~/.sh_aliases` and source it within your *profile and *rc files.

The next time you open a command prompt (or refresh it with `exec bash -login`), you can update by typing `update-tex`.

#### Installing Non-Libre Fonts from CTAN

There’s a bit of a gotcha if you want to install [getnonfreefonts](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) from TUG.  You might be tempted to install to your user directory, because that’s the only way that works out of the box.  **You want to install as `--sys`, not `--user`.  Installing 8-bit fonts as a user is a trap.**  If you install as user, the installer will run `updmap` as a user, which will create a font map in your user directory.  That will appear to work at first, but it will hide the system map from you and not be updated when you update the system map, so your map file will get more and more out of date.

You have to use a little trick to install it.  The command you have to run for the installer to work is

```
sudo -u tex -E --preserve-env=PATH $(which texlua) install-getnonfreefonts
```

This command creates a perl script to install the fonts, which you run with

```
sudo -u tex -E --preserve-env=PATH $(kpsewhich getnonfreefonts.pl) --sys --all --refreshmap --http
```

#### Installing Other Local Files

Sometimes, you might want to download TeX files that are not available as TeX Live packages, such as your publisher’s class file or the Type 1 fonts for Georgian. You usually want to put these in a subdirectory of `TEXMFLOCAL` (`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`) . rather than `TEXMFHOME` (`~/texmf/`) .  You can copy a directory with `sudo -u tex cp -r`.  After manually installing new files, run

```
sudo -u tex -E $(which texhash)
sudo -u tex -E $(which updmap-sys)
```

This makes sure your indices and map files are up to date.

If you only need them for one project, you can copy them to your project directory.

#### Installing and Using Fonts

You can install new fonts for your user account by saving them to `~/.fonts/`, or for everyone by saving them to `/usr/local/share/fonts/`.

You might want to add your TeX tree to the system font paths.  (Or even need to, for XeTeX to consistently find them.)  The file with the script to do this is `texlive-fontconfig.conf`, and you can enable it by creating a symbolic link to it in the directory `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive2020.conf
```

I additionally created a file with the same format to index the fonts in my TEXMFLOCAL tree.  I saved the following as `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texmf-local.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype</dir>    
</fontconfig>
```

I gave these files a low number, such as `09`, so that they will be searched before the system directories.  The fonts in my TeX directories are usually more up-to-date.

Both XeTeX and LuaTeX should automatically refresh their databases the next time you request a font it doesn’t know about, but you can manually make them do it with

```
sudo fc-cache -fsv
luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v
```

#### Other Optional Stuff

Some people recommend making a dummy `apt` package to prevent a second version of `texlive` from being automatically installed.  I personally have not had that problem.

Comment: If you put the path in `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh` as shown above, then instead of the long alias to use tlmgr, you can just say `sudo -i tlmgr` and the profile will still apply.

Comment: @musarithmia That’s a good tip. I have the alias so I can just type `update-tex` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> This is intended as a complement to cfr's answer
>   (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/105447) for those who wish the
>   convenience of the GUI for the use of `tlmgr`.

If you login in the terminal with `su texlive` you won't be able to run `tlmgr --gui` because the user `texlive` is not allowed by default to start a gui in your regular user's session (I'm not sure this is the best terminology for that). But you can allow it explicitly. For that, you should first run, as your regular user:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:texlive
```

And then login as `texlive` and run `tlmgr`:

```
su -l texlive
tlmgr --gui
```

If, besides that, you want to setup a launcher, you could add `xhost +SI:localuser:texlive` at the end of your `~/.profile` (or equivalent in your system), logout, login back, and then create `~/.local/share/applications/tlmgr.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=TeX Live Manager
Comment=Manages TeX Live packages
Icon=system-software-update
Exec=gksu -d -u texlive -D "TeX Live Manager" '/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr --gui'
Categories=Office;
Terminal=false
```

The path to `tlmgr` should be set as appropriate in your system (in doubt, use `which tlmgr`). Furthermore, `gksu` must be set with `gksu-properties`, setting "authentication mode" = "su".

Comment: @cfr, if you have comments or repairs, I'm all ears.